# OpenCV: "camera calibrate" Why non-planar calibration rigs need initial guess?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

Acccording to OpenCV doc, the reason of "For non-planar calibration rigs the initial intrinsic matrix must be specified" is on "initialization of intrinsic parameters"

OPENCV: calibrateCamera()  [latest-doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html):

> Currently, initialization of intrinsic parameters (when CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS is not set) is only implemented for planar calibration patterns (where Z-coordinates of the object points must be all zeros). 3D calibration rigs can also be used as long as initial cameraMatrix is provided.

What happened in "**initialization of intrinsic parameters**"? Why it cannot be done (or it is hard) for **3D rigs**?

How much will the initial guess affect camera calibration?

Comment: just give it a guess. distortion coefficients all 0. camera matrix calculated from image resolution and field of view (involves an arctan, that's all)

Comment: I tried, `fx/fy=1 fx = resolution_width/(2*tan(FOV_w/2)) cx = resolution_width/2 cy = resolution_height/2` It didn't work out.

Comment: looks correct. the equation, derived from application of the camera matrix, is: `tan(hfov/2) * fx = width/2`. equation analogously for vertical FoV and diagonal FoV (for square pixels, fx=fy=fd). if that doesn't work, perhaps present your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the opencv source code, `cvInitIntrinsicParams2D` uses vanishing points and a homography to estimate focal length. Homographies only work for planar scenes. It will still have errors because of distortion etc. Maybe you can map your 3D calibration pattern to something planar? I cant tell how important is the quality of the initial guess for the rest of the calibration process.

PROBABLY, it would be quite easy to adapt the algorithm to first extract 2D planes from a 3D rig, if there are clear 2D planes in that rig (e.g. identical z coordinate for a good number of points). If you are able to extract such a plane but arent able to adapt the code: Use the high level intrinsicGuess function, which is exposed in the API and feed that guessed intrinsics matrix to your calibration.

Here's the source code, availabel in modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp (opencv 4.5.2):

```
    CV_IMPL void cvInitIntrinsicParams2D( const CvMat* objectPoints,
                         const CvMat* imagePoints, const CvMat* npoints,
                         CvSize imageSize, CvMat* cameraMatrix,
                         double aspectRatio )
{
    Ptr<CvMat> matA, _b, _allH;

    int i, j, pos, nimages, ni = 0;
    double a[9] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    double H[9] = {0}, f[2] = {0};
    CvMat _a = cvMat( 3, 3, CV_64F, a );
    CvMat matH = cvMat( 3, 3, CV_64F, H );
    CvMat _f = cvMat( 2, 1, CV_64F, f );

    CV_Assert(npoints);
    CV_Assert(CV_MAT_TYPE(npoints->type) == CV_32SC1);
    CV_Assert(CV_IS_MAT_CONT(npoints->type));
    nimages = npoints->rows + npoints->cols - 1;

    if( (CV_MAT_TYPE(objectPoints->type) != CV_32FC3 &&
        CV_MAT_TYPE(objectPoints->type) != CV_64FC3) ||
        (CV_MAT_TYPE(imagePoints->type) != CV_32FC2 &&
        CV_MAT_TYPE(imagePoints->type) != CV_64FC2) )
        CV_Error( CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "Both object points and image points must be 2D" );

    if( objectPoints->rows != 1 || imagePoints->rows != 1 )
        CV_Error( CV_StsBadSize, "object points and image points must be a single-row matrices" );

    matA.reset(cvCreateMat( 2*nimages, 2, CV_64F ));
    _b.reset(cvCreateMat( 2*nimages, 1, CV_64F ));
    a[2] = (!imageSize.width) ? 0.5 : (imageSize.width - 1)*0.5;
    a[5] = (!imageSize.height) ? 0.5 : (imageSize.height - 1)*0.5;
    _allH.reset(cvCreateMat( nimages, 9, CV_64F ));

    // extract vanishing points in order to obtain initial value for the focal length
    for( i = 0, pos = 0; i < nimages; i++, pos += ni )
    {
        CV_DbgAssert(npoints->data.i);
        CV_DbgAssert(matA && matA->data.db);
        CV_DbgAssert(_b && _b->data.db);
        double* Ap = matA->data.db + i*4;
        double* bp = _b->data.db + i*2;
        ni = npoints->data.i[i];
        double h[3], v[3], d1[3], d2[3];
        double n[4] = {0,0,0,0};
        CvMat _m, matM;
        cvGetCols( objectPoints, &matM, pos, pos + ni );
        cvGetCols( imagePoints, &_m, pos, pos + ni );

        cvFindHomography( &matM, &_m, &matH );
        CV_DbgAssert(_allH && _allH->data.db);
        memcpy( _allH->data.db + i*9, H, sizeof(H) );

        H[0] -= H[6]*a[2]; H[1] -= H[7]*a[2]; H[2] -= H[8]*a[2];
        H[3] -= H[6]*a[5]; H[4] -= H[7]*a[5]; H[5] -= H[8]*a[5];

        for( j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
        {
            double t0 = H[j*3], t1 = H[j*3+1];
            h[j] = t0; v[j] = t1;
            d1[j] = (t0 + t1)*0.5;
            d2[j] = (t0 - t1)*0.5;
            n[0] += t0*t0; n[1] += t1*t1;
            n[2] += d1[j]*d1[j]; n[3] += d2[j]*d2[j];
        }

        for( j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
            n[j] = 1./std::sqrt(n[j]);

        for( j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
        {
            h[j] *= n[0]; v[j] *= n[1];
            d1[j] *= n[2]; d2[j] *= n[3];
        }

        Ap[0] = h[0]*v[0]; Ap[1] = h[1]*v[1];
        Ap[2] = d1[0]*d2[0]; Ap[3] = d1[1]*d2[1];
        bp[0] = -h[2]*v[2]; bp[1] = -d1[2]*d2[2];
    }

    cvSolve( matA, _b, &_f, CV_NORMAL + CV_SVD );
    a[0] = std::sqrt(fabs(1./f[0]));
    a[4] = std::sqrt(fabs(1./f[1]));
    if( aspectRatio != 0 )
    {
        double tf = (a[0] + a[4])/(aspectRatio + 1.);
        a[0] = aspectRatio*tf;
        a[4] = tf;
    }

    cvConvert( &_a, cameraMatrix );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! It indeed answer why "initialization of intrinsic parameters" cannot work on 3D rigs.

Comment: have a look at the edited part. There might be a simple hack to guess the intrinsics from your 3D rig.

Comment: However > "Maybe you can map your 3D calibration pattern to something planar? "  <br/> I'm not sure this will work. Because It will break the connection between object and image points. For example, if object faces its side to camera. There will be no transformation to project object points on image correctly. And thanks anyway!